# Difference between finish() and finishAndRemoveTask()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have little confusion between `finish()` method and `finishAndRemoveTask()` method. If any one have idea about it than please explain difference between them.

Comment: @KingofMasses : I have to get path of selected path not for share . So this is not duplicate .Please read my question

Comment: Please do not re-use this question to ask a completely different question. Instead, please ask a new question.

Comment: @Matt : sorry for that but i am blocked to ask new question so i try to reuse my old questions.

Comment: @Matt : So now what should i do if i am not able to ask a question ?

Comment: Read the link I included in my comment.

Comment: Following @matt's rollback in Aug 2015, this question was metamorphosed again, as has also happened on another question. I have rolled the question back so that it agrees with most of the answers provided. Unfortunately this has made Ganpat Kaliya's work redundant, so I have asked for that answer to be deleted.

Comment: Hi Anand. I put in a lot of volunteer effort here to tidy posts up, so please do not undo my work without pinging me first to discuss. Once I rolled this back, I added some formatting into it - if it is to remain open I think it should at least be nicely formatted. Thank you.

Comment: @halfer : Thank you for correction and supporting me

Answer (score 7):

`finish()` closes the current activity and optionally propagates the result of this activity to whoever launched it.

`finishAndRemoveTask()` closes the activity **and** removes the task as a part of finishing the root activity of the task. The task is also removed from recents.

Comment: @anand - Strider is right, u cant able to see the activity in recent task in the  main screen

Answer (score 2):

`finish()` - close your activity. Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.

`finishAndRemoveTask()` - Finishes all activities in this task and removes it from the recent tasks list.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be familiar what is a "Task" and "Back Stack"

A task is a collection of activities that users interact with when performing a certain job. The activities are arranged in a stack (the back stack), in the order in which each activity is opened. For more details, you can refer to: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

`finish()` will close the active Activity 
`finishAndRemoveTask()` will close the active Activity and clear any pending tasks.